# Error Syntax 'send' en Javascript

Tags: javascript, websocket

Tengo un problema con mi código de javascript de la autenticación del usuario (mediante su id) para mi conexión websocket. Lo que ocurre es que me sale un problema al enviar la función *connectCallback(); con los datos del usuario* y no sé porque sucede.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

flashsocket.js (línea 47) y client.php (línea 24, que sería la función *connectCallback();*)

```
    function authenticate(ssoTicket) {
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({
        "handler": "authentication",
        "ssoTicket": ssoTicket
    }));

    session = ssoTicket;
}

function connectCallback(){
            authenticate(<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>);
            console.log('Authentication sent to user: ' + <?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>);
        }

// habboflashclient.js (línea 1219, esta impulsa la función connectCallback a funcionar)
setTimeout(function() {connectCallback(); });
```

flashsocket.js
https://pastebin.com/X35kd1WL

Comment: Si estoy entendiendo bien, el problema parecería ser que `socket` (`L48`) es `undefined`. Diría que te esta faltando llamar algún método para inicializar la variable.

Comment: @Marcos podrías decirme cuál podría ser el método?

Comment: No sabría decirte sin ver el archivo `flashsocket.js` completo y/o sin leer la documentación referente al mismo

Comment: Ya lo coloqué en pastebin. Échale un vistazo y gracias de todas formas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te decía en [mi comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/277631/error-syntax-send-en-javascript?noredirect=1#comment510759_277631), el problema se debe a que `socket` es `undefined`.

#### Solución:

Revisando el archivo [`flashsocket.js`](https://pastebin.com/X35kd1WL) podemos observar que el método `connect()` (línea 8) es encargado de inicializar la variable, por lo que tu código debería llamar antes de ejecutar `authenticate`.

Así por ejemplo:

```
function connectCallback(){
  connect();
  authenticate(<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>);
  console.log('Authentication sent to user: ' + <?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>);
}
```

Comment: Sí funciona, pero no me muestra en la consola lo de ** Authentication sent to user: la id del usuario **. Cosa que también requiero porque eso hará la autenticación del usuario mediante la socket para mi juego.

Comment: @SrArepa, se complica saber que puede estar pasando sin [un ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). ¿No estas recibiendo algún otro error?

Comment: No te preocupes, ya lo solucioné. Gracias amigo :)